# How to update a field in table withrepect to the data in another table Coloumn using Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables namely **Enquiry_details** and **Customer_details**, if customer name from **Enquiry_details** table is already in customer_details table then need to update the Enquiry_details table status of Existing customer field to YES otherwise No.

This should be done using trigger. Kindly help with the trigger code.

Thanks,
Acube.

Comment: **Fields in Enquiry Details** 1. Customer Name and 2. Existing Customer, **Fields in Customer Details** 1. Customer Name.

Comment: You have the answer. Just write a `before insert` trigger

Comment: can you help me with the trigger code...

Comment: kindly help, since this is a priority one issue for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`create trigger track_customer before insert on enquiry_details
for each row
begin
    if (select count(*) from customer_details where customer_name = NEW.customer_name) <= 0 then
     set NEW.existing_customer = 'No';
    else
     set NEW.existing_customer = 'Yes';
    end if;
end;//`

Comment: i am getting a error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6

Comment: I tested this on sqlfiddle and it works fine. You can check it [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8ea7/2/0](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8ea7/2/0)

Comment: thanks Clement, i sorted out the problem, its now working fine.

Answer (score 0):

working code is below. thanks to **Clement89** for helping me.

```
create trigger track_customer_Exists 
before insert on enquiry_details 
for each row
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO enquiry_details_seq VALUES (NULL);
  SET NEW.Created_Date = NOW();
  SET NEW.Submitted_Date = NOW();
  SET NEW.Slno = coalesce((select max(Slno) from enquiry_details), 0) + 1;
  SET NEW.Enq_Id = CONCAT('ENQ', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 5, '0'));
if (select count(*) from customer_details where Customer_Name = NEW.Customer_Name) <= 0 
then 
set NEW.Existing_Customer = 'No'; 
else 
set NEW.Existing_Customer = 'Yes'; 
end if;
END
```